# Does wp_remote_post support asynchronous request?

Tags: wp-remote-post

I want to post to multiple rest API endpoints with `wp_remote_post` but don't want to wait for the response back and keep continuing code execution. Some popular clients like guzzle etc. support asynchronous Http call. Does wp_remote_post also support the same? If yes how can I achieve that?